# "Emit" and "On" socket IO, Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

I am just starting to try out node.js and its very likely that I am mistaken so please bear with me :)

From what I understand, the emit function sends out a custom event and on picks up events and then does something.

Here is of bit of the code from the book I'm learning from.

```
socket.on('rooms', function(rooms) {
    console.log("room received");
    $('#room-list').empty();
    for(var room in rooms) {
        room = room.substring(1, room.length);
        if (room != '') {
            $('#room-list').append(divEscapedContentElement(room));
        }
    }
    $('#room-list div').click(function() {
        chatApp.processCommand('/join ' + $(this).text());
        $('#send-message').focus();
    });
});

setInterval(function() {
    socket.emit('rooms');
    console.log("room emitted");
}, 1000);
```

It is logging "room emitted" in the console every second however, it isn't logging "room received"

This shows that it should be emitting the rooms event and the on function should be picking it up. However for some reason it isn't.

Is there something I'm doing wrong???

Comment: How are you instantiating `socket`? How does the serverside code look like?

Comment: I ended up figuring it out after a long time but thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`socket.emit()` sends information from the server to the client(s).

`socket.on()` receives information sent from the clients to the server.

You can't emit a message from the server to the server unless the server is connected as a client to itself.

Hopefully this was helpful.

Comment: I fixed the error. It was with another socket.on that was on my server.  All the code above is on the client side, so how does that work if socket.emit only sends code from the server to the client.  From my code it seems that the client emits and event to the server checking for rooms and then the server receives the event and re-emits the room event with all the current rooms back to all clients.

Comment: However with your definition of what emit and on does, it doesn't seem like the clients should be able to emit events or receive them, but in my code it works so I'm a bit confused lol

Comment: My description was a little bit poor. Let me refine:

`socket.on()` will receive messages from whoever you're connected to. In the server's case, this is messages from the clients. In the client's case, these are server messages. `socket.emit()` will send messages across your connection(s). Again, in the client's case, this sends messages back to the server.

Since the server isn't connected to itself, if you emit a "room" message, the server will not simultaneously receive a "room" message.